# Seeking Google Sign-in Android plugin error: 'Could not create task ':google_sign_in_android:compileDebugUnitTestSources'

Tags: android, flutter

when ever i debug my application

The supplied phased action failed with an exception.
Could not create task ':google_sign_in_android:compileDebugUnitTestSources'.
this and base files have different roots: D:\flutter\talker\build\google_sign_in_android and C:\Users\anura\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\google_sign_in_android-6.1.20\android.

this is the error it throwing

how to solve this error step by step